# Apache camel create two seperate files with same name but different extension

Tags: java, apache-camel

I want to create two files with same name but different extension basically below code where I am able to create the file `abc.dat` at the same time I want to create another file `ex` `abc.txt` which will be empty at the same location as `abc.dat` :

```
from("file:C:\\input?filter=#testFilter").split(body().tokenize("\n")).
streaming().setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple(newFileName+".dat")).bean(LineParser.class, "process").to("file:C:\\output"+ Constants.getMapping().get(argumentName)+"?fileExist=Append");
```

thanks in advance.

Comment: Take a look at the doneFileName option of the file component which can create empty _done_ files. https://github.com/apache/camel/blob/master/camel-core/src/main/docs/file-component.adoc

Answer (score 3):

To create second empty file in same directory, use `donefileName` option with the help of [camel file language](http://camel.apache.org/file-language.html) (require [toD](http://camel.apache.org/message-endpoint.html)).

```
from("file:C:\\input?filter=#testFilter")
    .split(body().tokenize("\n"))
    .streaming()
    .setHeader(Exchange.FILE_NAME,simple(newFileName+".dat"))
    .bean(LineParser.class, "process")
    .toD("file:C:\\output"+ Constants.getMapping().get(argumentName)+"?fileExist=Append&donefileName=${file:name.noext}.txt")
```

p.s. `${file:name.noext}` mean `abc` part from data file name `abc.txt`

Comment: thanks for the response but when I tried dong above and can see the file getting created but I am also getting : java.io.FileNotFoundException:c:\output\abc.txt does not exists

Answer (score 0):

Actually you need to have two endpoints here, which will do same operation creating file with different extension. Using so you can achieve it.
Before that you have to store the body content to property, to avoid losing the file content after first end point.